# Microsoft Graph, upload to sharepoint drive: The caller is not authenticated

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

This work on my application hosted on **localhost**:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/test.sharepoint.com,edc2dd46-cea8-4b10-a872-cd1a55ba4529,b14c0787-d4c1-4f4a-9a6c-7e010d794be9/drives/b!Rt3C7ajOEEuocs0aVbpFKYcHTLHB1EpPmmx-AQ15S-nygMtHkkWNRaaOc2GebusJ/items/01VI7PMEF6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ?%24filter=folder ne null&%24select=id%2cfolder%2cname%2cparentReference%2cwebUrl"

"https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/test.sharepoint.com,edc2dd46-cea8-4b10-a872-cd1a55ba4529,b14c0787-d4c1-4f4a-9a6c-7e010d794be9/drives/b!Rt3C7ajOEEuocs0aVbpFKYcHTLHB1EpPmmx-AQ15S-nygMtHkkWNRaaOc2GebusJ/items/01VI7PMEF6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ?%24filter=folder ne null&%24select=id%2cfolder%2cname%2cparentReference%2cwebUrl"

"https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/sites/test.sharepoint.com,edc2dd46-cea8-4b10-a872-cd1a55ba4529,b14c0787-d4c1-4f4a-9a6c-7e010d794be9/drives/b!Rt3C7ajOEEuocs0aVbpFKYcHTLHB1EpPmmx-AQ15S-nygMtHkkWNRaaOc2GebusJ/root:/Presentation.en-GB.pptx:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession"
```

But when I have uploaded the application on production server on azure as webapp.

I get this error by trying to find sharepoint site by id and creating upload session.

**Outer:**
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound
Message: The resource could not be found.

**Inner:**
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: unauthenticated
Message: The caller is not authenticated.

Why does it work on localhost and not my azure app?
The app registration are different for development and production but the permissions are same.

The only difference I know is that I added **Sites.Read.All** permission later and not when I registered the app for the production in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.

I am using the Microsoft Graph client to get get the access token.
I have also tried to delete all offline-tokens but it does not work.

If I remember right when I added the permission **Sites.Read.All** I got a new consent request.

Permission enabled in the app:
email, Files.Read, Files.ReadWrite, File.ReadWrite.AppFolder, offline_access, openid, profile, Site.Read.All, User.Read

Is anything wrong?

**Production Login:**

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 kid: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q"
}.
{
 aud: "f53962c3-2bd4-4302-adcf-49d9a93ccef0",
 iss: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID/v2.0",
 iat: 1502142424,
 nbf: 1502142424,
 exp: 1502146324,
 aio: "ATQAy/8DAAAAo99zdMc3jCP7sR8Zw0iKijdu1Nv2AeJOpJ65OHtXb0o8QjTm9O320mHxIAv5tWJw",
 c_hash: "APreKq7N3Y0oG8SP6ipZdA",
 name: "First name Last name",
 nonce: "636377394901824543.ZWQ4MGVkYmEtYTMzMS00ZDUyLTgzZmYtYWFjMmRkNWRjNzhhNTAxMWUyYzItOGNhNi00N2IzLTk5MGEtMTVmYTlhYzBkNDVk",
 oid: "4f64d4db-8115-4f19-8554-bedf20688226",
 preferred_username: "firstname.lastname@company.com",
 sub: "rxGHRTX9YHogzaC_HgOmXvoKJ0Xye6Rk5HPAjLphQRc",
 tid: "34e9a1f3-23e1-4ead-b2fd-41660c25cc47",
 ver: "2.0"
}.
```

**Local Login:**

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 kid: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q"
}.
{
 aud: "36d2abdd-2363-4ff9-b597-77d41e0e3b81",
 iss: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID/v2.0",
 iat: 1502173871,
 nbf: 1502173871,
 exp: 1502177771,
 aio: "ATQAy/8EAAAA2JCq8vpq6La3M0KIKWw1vgJOfhDQyurYRhbCR47qSjByGzPkyZX0zi5y9uYCQS+q",
 c_hash: "3JkkVwHgmYiHvR-gVdb22w",
 name: "First name Last name",
 nonce: "636377709651517241.MDNkOWNhYzMtYjk4NC00OTBkLWI2Y2EtYzU5NmM0NWZjOGExNWQxZmU3MTgtN2RhYS00NjVlLTkwZDgtZjIwOGY4NTcyNTZi",
 oid: "4f64d4db-8115-4f19-8554-bedf20688226",
 preferred_username: "firstname.lastname@company.com",
 sub: "MRN4y1TZ-qG1uxrL7ozf8KbBm0VbcbH7djaKK187qH8",
 tid: "34e9a1f3-23e1-4ead-b2fd-41660c25cc47",
 ver: "2.0"
}.
```

*Also read comments for more details.*

Comment: You confirmed that the scopes is being included in your token? You can parse the JWT using http://calebb.net/.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Hello, I will try calebb.net tomorrow, thank you. But I have confirmed that both web.config contain the same scope. I just can't find what is different from production and local to not make it work. By the way the product I am developing can save both to OneDrive and SharePoint where the first one working on both environment  while the later one just work on the local.

Comment: Same SharePoint server instance or separate prod and test? Currious if issue is configuration rather than code here.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yes it is same SharePoint instance. I have parsed JWT from the production environment. It is also the same Office 365 account I am using for the testing. The only thing I know that is different is the Azure App and the url is http://localhost:xxxx/ and the production has https://xxx.example.com/ but both those should be correct set in both environment and azure app. Otherwise OneDrive should not have worked, right?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Hello again, now I have uploaded the local JWT. I have also double checked if site-id,drive-id and drive-item-id was same on both environment which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error by using http://calebb.net/ on the token after the login.

The Azure app registration was missing a permission, **Files.ReadWrite.All** but development did neither have it, but the permissions was somehow included in the scope.

Bug in Azure? If I remember correct I had included lot of permissions in the app registration and then removed most of them including Files.ReadWrite.All.

Even when my WebApp did not include the permission in the scope and the app registration, the permission Files.ReadWrite.All was kept in the scope for existing users per app registration. Which is why it works on the development environment.

Thank you Marc LaFleur - MSFT.

Comment: I'm not clear on _exactly_ what happened here but I'm glad you got it working. I will say that generally I recommend using the v2 Endpoint and requesting your scopes dynamically (i.e. in the request). This makes it a LOT easier to debug and migrate between dev/test and production.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I was in hurry writen my answer I think it came out wrong now it should be easier to understand I hope. Thank you I will look into v2 Endpoint.