# Microsoft Graph, some users: AuthenticationFailure, Caller needs to authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We have built a Microsoft MVC application using Microsoft Graph with Owin Oauth authentication. Everything seems to work for most users but there is small amount of users where the silent token is not working.

Every time this user try to access Microsoft Graph we get AuthenticationFailure, Caller needs to authenticate but the user can sign in.

For some reason this user can now access One Drive without we doing anything but few days ago it did not work. But this person can't access SharePoint sites. This person also have higher permission than me, he is one of the Office 365/SharePoint admin.

If we check the token the cache is updated for those users when they try to login again and I have also tried to delete all caches to see if it works.

We can't find anything wrong with the code.

**Not working:**

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 nonce: "AQABAAAAAAA9kTklhVy7SJTGAzR-p1Bczrtr_wq7McwtSbPfo4aECokKdbsOZ1i6087v4nyBvi1qnYdsVoB1VvdentDl9EkV_det7OZvBatOHJhJDglpLCAA",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q",
 kid: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/GUID/",
 iat: 1503302799,
 nbf: 1503302799,
 exp: 1503306699,
 acr: "1",
 aio: "Y2FgYEgImX+jxi7wfviVJq/tp+LTb3+1+dhVdybllXxEqPnsvC4A",
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ],
 app_displayname: "App",
 appid: "f53962c3-2bd4-4302-adcf-49d9a93ccef0",
 appidacr: "1",
 deviceid: "08c173b6-e694-4df7-9009-33d1bcd4816a",
 e_exp: 262800,
 family_name: "Last name",
 given_name: "First name",
 ipaddr: "217.10.98.37",
 name: "First name Last name",
 oid: "794781b4-0d07-45ba-886b-39de7db6cb26",
 platf: "3",
 puid: "10037FFE822DF7CE",
 scp: "Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Sites.Read.All User.Read",
 signin_state: [
  "kmsi"
 ],
 sub: "AWDO_-uMHsb5Z9_3_NZZXt0B9raHXf4WJDQyYDIndnw",
 tid: "34e9a1f3-23e1-4ead-b2fd-41660c25cc47",
 unique_name: "Firstname.Lastname@Company.com",
 upn: "Firstname.Lastname@Company.com",
 uti: "vS8Dt5Ti8UC-MfWzW9w4AA",
 ver: "1.0",
 wids: [
  "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
 ]
}.
```

**Working:**

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 nonce: "AQABAAAAAAA9kTklhVy7SJTGAzR-p1Bc8SYQkFxaUuQmF53LfeErsJ2wrzDuI3DNK5BeYrzqN2n6wBbg6m01AElY4d3MBVS5f6vEaT7zzHhxH4A-76fJmiAA",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q",
 kid: "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/GUID/",
 iat: 1503302938,
 nbf: 1503302938,
 exp: 1503306838,
 acr: "1",
 aio: "ASQA2/8EAAAA29TpgRDNkbS6xeBrV4uP2ap1cS5uk8q8f6w/S9BDZAA=",
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ],
 app_displayname: "App",
 appid: "f53962c3-2bd4-4302-adcf-49d9a93ccef0",
 appidacr: "1",
 e_exp: 262800,
 family_name: "Last name",
 given_name: "First name",
 ipaddr: "217.10.98.37",
 name: "First name Last name",
 oid: "4f64d4db-8115-4f19-8554-bedf20688226",
 platf: "3",
 puid: "1003BFFD8CBEE8BE",
 scp: "Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Sites.Read.All User.Read",
 signin_state: [
  "kmsi"
 ],
 sub: "QrnV0lz7zBFkTPM9EJDavezILP96Uig45PpFxhRp3gk",
 tid: "34e9a1f3-23e1-4ead-b2fd-41660c25cc47",
 unique_name: "Firstname.Lastname@Company.com",
 upn: "Firstname.Lastname@Company.com",
 uti: "d9WDLYW2uE2UDIl6u9BKAA",
 ver: "1.0"
}.
```

We are using code from:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample

Here is little bit of background:
[Microsoft Graph, upload to sharepoint drive: The caller is not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547735/microsoft-graph-upload-to-sharepoint-drive-the-caller-is-not-authenticated)

Comment: Can it be because he is admin? Maybe Sites.ReadWrite.All is required?